# String to list, python

Tags: python, string, list

Let's say I have something like this in a file:

```
[[(A,B), (B,C)],[(x,y), (z,v)]]
```

I want this as a python list of lists. How do I do that?

In the end, I would like to be able to iterate through the rows and the columns of this array, and get each pair of adjacent values to compare them.

Comment: Or `ast.literal_eval` depending on what `A`, `B`, `C`, ... look like.

Comment: Do you need this as output: `[[('A','B'), ('B','C')],[('x','y'), ('z','v')]]`? Or do you have values for A,B,C...?

Comment: Much better to avoid `eval`. I'd prefer using a parser(maybe even `ast.parse`, or, as mgilson proposed, `ast.literal_eval` if those letters represent literals).

Answer (score 3):

More esoteric way of doing it:

```
import yaml
from string import maketrans

s = "[[(A,B), (B,C)],[(x,y), (z,v)]]"    
yaml.load(s.translate(maketrans("()", "[]")))
```

out:

```
[[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']], [['x', 'y'], ['z', 'v']]]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> import re,ast
>>> st='[[(A,BC), (B,C)],[(x,y), (z,v)]]'
>>> ast.literal_eval(re.sub(r'(\w+)',r"'\1'",st))
[[('A', 'BC'), ('B', 'C')], [('x', 'y'), ('z', 'v')]]
```

If you really do want a LoLoL rather than a LoLoT (as above), do this:

```
def rep(match):
    if match.group(1)=='(': return '['
    if match.group(1)==')': return ']'
    return "'{}'".format(match.group(1))

st='[[(A,B), (B,C)],[(x,y), (z,v)]]'
st=re.sub(r'(\w+|[\(\)])', rep,st)
>>> ast.literal_eval(st)
[[['A', 'B'], ['B', 'C']], [['x', 'y'], ['z', 'v']]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you've read the line from the file:

```
import ast

parsed_list = ast.literal_eval(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Pure python...

```
s = "[[(A,B), (B,C)],[(x,y), (z,v)]]"

print s

s = filter(None, s[1:-1].replace(",[", "").replace("[", "").replace(" ", "").split(']'))

for i,t in enumerate(s):
    t = filter(None, t.replace(",(", "").replace("(", "").split(')'))
    t = [tuple(x.split(",")) for x in t]
    s[i] = t

print s
```

Output:

```
>>> 
[[(A,B), (B,C)],[(x,y), (z,v)]]
[[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C')], [('x', 'y'), ('z', 'v')]]
>>>
```